# How to extend jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I have tried using other examples on Stackoverflow to extend jquery objects but i have been unsuccessful.

```
    var z = {

        vars: {
            x: $('#c')
        }

    };

    var y = {

        v: $(this).val(a),
        h: $(this).html(a)

    };

    $.extend(y,z);

    alert(y.vars.h.x);
```

Comment: did you mean `y.vars.x`?

Comment: Totally didn't read this before I answered.

Comment: This might help: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: `y.vars.h.x` - where is `y.vars.h` supposed to come from? Try `alert(y.vars.x);`

Comment: $.extend is supposed to essentially merge z with y, so that y includes vars and also v and h. So in your example y.v works, y.h works and y.vars works, as does y.vars.x. But y.vars.h.x makes no sense. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish with JQuery extend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have them extending correctly, you're just calling them wrong afterwards. I put the following together to help with debugging how it works.

```
var z = {
    vars: {
        x: "var_Z.X"
    }
};

var y = {
    v: "var_Y.V",
    h: "var_Y.H"
};

$.extend( y, z );

// Output
    ( y.vars.x ) // var_Z.X
    ( y.v ) // var_Y.V
    ( y.h ) // var_Y.H

    ( z.vars.x ) // var_Z.X
    ( z.v ) // undefined
    ( z.h ) // undefined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/6YvHw/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )
```

Keep in mind that the target object (first argument) will be modified, and will also be returned from `$.extend()`.
If, however, you want to preserve both of the original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

**Example**:

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

**Output is**:

```
{"apple":0,"banana":{"price":200},"cherry":97,"durian":100}
```

**Explanation**:

The merge performed by `$.extend()` is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an `object` or `array`, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object.
The values are not merged. This can be seen in the example below by examining the value of `banana`. However, by passing `true` for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/